# Can we really write expectations of -arbitrary- Borel measurable functions of absolutely continuous random variables as Riemann integrals?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, expected-value

**Background.**  Consider the Law of the Unconscious Statistician (LOTUS):

Let $X$ be a random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.  Let $g$ be a Borel measurable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  If $Y = g \circ X$, then
\begin{align}
 E(Y) = \int_\mathbb{R} g \; dP_X
\label{eqn:expectation_as_integral_wrt_induced_probability_measure} 
\end{align}
where $P_X$ is the probability measure induced by $X$ [i.e. for all Borel sets B, $P_X(B)=P\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in B\}$].

**Question.**  Now in Ash and Doleans-Dade's *Probability and Measure Theory* (pp.190, second edition), it is said that under the conditions of LOTUS, and if additionally $X$ is a random variable with density $f$, then
\begin{align}
 E(Y)  = \int_\mathbb{R} g(x) \,d{P_X} \stackrel{(1)}{=} \int_\mathbb{R} g(x) f(x)\,d{x} \quad \quad \quad \quad (*)
\end{align}
in the sense that if either integral exists, then so does the other, and the two are equal.

But does equation (1) really hold in general for all Borel measurable $g$?   By using change of variables with Radon-Nikodym derivatives, it is immediate that $d{P_X} = f d\mu$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.  So that converts the LHS of (1) to $\int_\mathbb{R} g(x) f(x) \,d{\mu}(x)$, and we are almost there.  But for $\int_\mathbb{R} g(x) f(x) \,d{\mu}(x)$ to become a Reimann integral, as (I assume) is the correct interpretation of the RHS of (1), we would need $gf$ to be continuous $\mu$-a.e., and that wouldn't seem to be the case for arbitrary Borel measurable $g$.

It seems that either

1. I am missing something about how to complete the proof.
2. Ash interprets the RHS of (1) as a Lebesgue rather than Reimann integral.
3. Ash made a mistake and Equation (*) holds only with further restrictions on $g$ than was originally stated.

**Update.**  My question was answered by the comment from Kurt G.

Comment: That is definitely a Lesbegue integral ($f$ is the density of $P_X$ w.r.t. Lesbegue measure!).

Nevertheless, one can actually write every expectation as (improper) Riemann integral - just not as in your formula -, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation.

Comment: It sounds like the confusion comes from assuming that $dx$ means Riemann integral which is something I never heard of. It is a Lebesgue integral whenever the integrand is not Riemann but still Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: I can't imagine what made you think it was a Riemann integral...

Comment: @KurtG.  Thank you.  I had indeed thought that  notationally meant Riemann integral.  I'm not sure what source (if any) led me to this conclusion, but if nothing else, my intuition was: If  can also mean Lebesgue, then it  would be unclear from $\int f(x) dx$ which integral was intended.  Kurt G's statement ("It is a Lebesgue integral whenever the integrand is not Riemann but still Lebesgue integrable.") obviously resolves this concern.   So my assumption must have been incorrect, and the answer to my question is given by option #2.     Really appreciate this critical clarification.